# Rate Me URL on app store before App Published

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, url, rate

I am implementing a rate me function in xcode 6.1 - Swift.

I am following [this](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-rate-me-using-uialertview-in-swift/) tutorial and my question is how do I find the URL for my app on the app store before it is published i.e. is there a default URL we add the App Name to pre-emptively?

- Using a AlertController to display rate me options

  ```
  var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Me", message: "Thanks for using Lab Cases- Ver 1 Newbrn and Obstetric Haematology", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate Lab Cases", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)

  alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }))

  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")

  alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

  }))
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
  alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }))


  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ```

And the call to the URL is here -

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)

            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks in advance
C

Comment: [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) is a great alternative to implementing this yourself and it has numerous localizations.

Comment: Thanks, is that obj c?

Comment: Yes it is in Objective-C. You can import it using a [Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Or if you'd like to expand on your `func` this would be a great reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the URL from https://itunesconnect.apple.com

Login with you apple id, go to the section of My Apps,Select the app(or create new)

On the submenu, there's More/View on App Store.

This is the link of actual app

Comment: Thanks, so I got the url although the app obviously wasn't found as haven't uploaded yet, when debugging I get a invalid address in browser, I'm guessing this is ok as the app is not yet available on the store?